# Spring jpa repository find rows by property and return only the latest one

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "forum_comment", schema = "public")
public class ForumCommentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post", nullable = false)
    private ForumPostEntity post;

    @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime created;
}
```

And i want to find the latest ForumComment that belongs to the ForumPost. I have `JpaRepository`:

```
public interface ForumCommentRepository extends JpaRepository<ForumCommentEntity, Long> {
    long countByPost(ForumPostEntity entity);
    LocalDateTime findAllByPostAndFindFirstByOrderByCreatedDesc(ForumPostEntity entity);
}
```

However it is complaining about not knowing `FindFirst` and so on What is the correct way to declare function that first filter by property and then order them and returns only the latest row?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the findAll at the beginning. It must be:

`findFirstByPostOrderByCreatedDesc`

Comment: and also make sure you have index on column created to avoid seq scans